# Round RangeSlider position values to 2 decimal places

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-slider

I'm trying to create a price range slider in Compose, I've found something that almost suits my needs:

```kotlin
@Composable
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterialApi::class)
fun RangeSliderSample() {
    var sliderPosition by remember { mutableStateOf(0f..100f) }
    Text(text = sliderPosition.toString(), style = MaterialTheme.typography.labelLarge)
    RangeSlider(
        values = sliderPosition,
        onValueChange = { sliderPosition = it },
        valueRange = 0f..100f,
        onValueChangeFinished = {
            // launch some business logic update with the state you hold
            // viewModel.updateSelectedSliderValue(sliderPosition)
        },
    )
}
```

however there is no (clear) way to round up the position/values to 2 decimal places (eg. 10.24 etc.) and I really need that

any tips / hints / links will be appreciated,

thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can round up the value:

```
var sliderPosition by remember { mutableStateOf(0f..100f) }
Text(
     text =  String.format("%.2f", sliderPosition.start) + " - " +
             String.format("%.2f", sliderPosition.endInclusive),
     style = MaterialTheme.typography.labelLarge
)
```

[image]